# How to resolve "Not a valid Win32 FileTime" error when getting data from a folder in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, excel-2016, filetime

I am using Excel 2016 and the latest version of Power BI to get data from a folder. However, I am encountering the following error message: "Expression.Error: Not a valid Win32 FileTime. Parameter name: fileTime Details: J:\PUBLIC\DRIVENAME". I am unsure what is causing this issue and how to resolve it.

Please review the question and provide any suggestions or solutions that may help me resolve this error.

Thank you in advance for your help!

What I tried: Data Source, from folder. Once I click edit or transform, I get the list of all the files in the folder, but 1 row is all ERROR. I have tried filtering by file extension and filtering by creation date to remove the error from the list of returned files.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Please post your code. You are giving us nothing to go by.

Comment: let
    Source = Folder.Files("J:\PUBLIC\DRIVENAME\SUBFOLDER"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] <> ".db")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Date.IsInCurrentDay([Date created])),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Filtered Rows1", {{"Date created", null}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"

Comment: Why doesn't replace errors with null work? The error row persists.

Comment: I'm excited to share an update and method to resolving the errors. Within the Power Query Editor, I opened the smaller individual sub directories within the main directory that was being scanned for files. The excel files were dated and the last date that would show up would be 1 day before the file with the error. Then I could navigate to that excel file with the error. I would open the file and there would be a break connection pop up. I would break the connection and save the file and the error for that subfolder would be resolved!!!